# How to create a page in a given SharePoint 2010 Pages Library using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'd like to be able to create a page in the Pages Library (and check whether it exists already).

I also need to be able to apply a custom page layout to it and then set it as the Home Page (as you can in the ribbon) for the given site.

I need to accomplish these three steps with PowerShell (I'm writing a deployment script).

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get your publishing web like this:

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $websiteUrl -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
$pweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($SPWeb)
```

get the list of pages:

```
$pages = $pweb.GetPublishingPages($pweb)

get a page layout:
$ctype = $psite.ContentTypes["Your Page Layout Content Type"]
$pageLayouts = $psite.GetPageLayouts($ctype, $true)
$pageLayouts | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.Title -eq "Your Page Layout Title")
  {
    $layout = $_;
  }
}
```

look for your page like this

```
$pages | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Name -eq "default.aspx")
    {
        $page = $_;
    }
}
```

update the layout this way

```
if ($page -ne $null)
{
    $page.CheckOut()
    $page.Layout  = $layout; 
    $page.Update();
}
```

create a page based on a layout like this

```
$page = $pages.Add("new.aspx", $layout)
$page.Title = "New Title"; 
$page.Update();
```

update other fields if needed

```
$item = $page.ListItem
if ($pg.PageContent -ne "")
{
    $item["Title"] = "Your Title";
    $item["Page Content"] = "Your content";
    $item.Update() 
}
```

check in & publish your page.

```
if ($page -ne $null)
{
    $item.File.CheckIn("")
    $item.File.Publish("")
    $item.File.Approve("")
}
```